# System of non linear equations with parameters

Tags: matlab, parameters, nonlinear-functions

I'm triying to solve a system of non linear equations in matlab. I am trying to use `fsolve` to solve the same system but with different parameters.

```
k1=0.01;
k2=0.05;
k3=10;
k4=100;
Ca0=1;
f2=@(C,tau) [Ca0-C(1)-tau*(k1*C(1)-k2*C(2)+k4*C(1).^2);C(2)-tau*(k1*C(1)-k2*C(2)-k3*C(2))];
t = linspace(0,1);
for i = 1:length(t)
 options=optimset('display','off');
 solution(i) = fsolve(f2,[2 0],options,t(i));
end
```

Then I need to plot the solution, but I keep getting `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.`

Comment: By the way, I follow the example from [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-4S9Qdoamw).,
Also, thanks in advance for any reply!

Comment: on which line is the error?

Comment: `fsolve` returns a `1x2` vector, but `solution(i)` only accepts a scalar.

Comment: @ Ander-Biguri, The error says `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in problema620 (line 19)
     solution(i) = fsolve(f2,[2 0],options,t(i));`

@TroyHaskin, Thank you!, I changed `solution(I) ` to `solution(:,I)` and now it's working!